# Can't accept answer for 'bountied' question on serverfault

Tags: support, bounty, accepted-answer

I asked this [question on serverfault](https://serverfault.com/questions/44995/how-to-work-out-the-wmi-class-name-from-its-perfmon-counter-name) some weeks ago and put a bounty of 50 rep on it (it got published with a bounty of 100 rep attached so I guess the system 'tops up' the bounty amount). When it came to the time for accepting an answer - I found that I couldn't i.e. I was not given the tick option at the side of the answers (as if I did not own the question). The best I could do was to upvote the answer which helped me the most - but that did not appear to present the user who answered my question with the 'prize reputation'.

Did I mess up somehow or is this a bug?

Comment: This is called an "unresolved bounty", has already been reported ( http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1413 ) and is "by design" for now. See also http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/13133/no-question-marked-answered-when-bounty-expired

Comment: Hmm. I'm pretty sure that I upvoted the answer I liked **before** the deadline. And I would have accepted it as the answer if I was able to. But then again, I am probably mistaken (otherwise many others would be seeing this same problem!). Thanks for that!

Comment: If you do not select any answer before the deadline, the most upvoted answer will be auto selected **if it has at least 2 upvotes**. Your preferred answer was only upvoted once. Hence no-autoselection, and "close bounty" means: no selection ever again (for now).

Answer (score 2):

Bounties are awarded within a week to the highest upvoted answer at the end of the time, or if you accept it sooner. If you offered the bounty "some weeks ago", and neither of the answers were upvoted, I suspect that the bounty merely timed out.